# "web_accessible_resources" manifest key is ignored if respective resources are injected into a file URL page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Recently my MV3 extension stopped working (although it was working before). After some research I found out that injected scripts/CSS fail to load despite they're listed in `web_accessible_resources` manifest key. These necessary resources are injected by my content script via `document.createElement`. It's worth noting that this problem only arises if these resources are injected into a page with a local file (`file://`) opened; there is no problem on `http://` pages.

I get `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` error for all injected resources:
[image: Blocked Error message]

Below is "web_accessible_resources" key in my manifest:

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
  {
    "resources": [
      "harviewer/*",
      "connection.js"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
  }
],
...
```

AFAIU it is correct, otherwise I'd get another error message like this:
[image]

"Allow access to file URLS" checkbox is checked for the extension:
[image]

I have no adblock-like extensions installed. Also I've tried to clear browser cache, with no luck.

So is it a bug or a feature? The current Chrome Dev docs don't mention such behaviour.

I've made a [MCVE](https://github.com/hindmost/mv3-web-resrcs-bug-reprex) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Seems like the linked source is for MV2. Maybe you accidentally moved web_accessible_resources of your MV3 json inside another section?

Comment: @wOxxOm No, this key is at the root level. Anyway if `web_accessible_resources` are specified wrong, Chrome would point out that in the console, like in the 2nd image above. It seems like Chrome rejects requests to JS scripts even if they're whitelisted in `web_accessible_resources`. But if so, why isn't there any mention about it in the docs?

Comment: @wOxxOm _Seems like the linked source is for MV2_ The source code is cross-browser, building to both MV2 (FF) and MV3 (Chrome). `public/manifest.json` is MV2, but it is changed accordingly for MV3 build.

Comment: It's either a bug in Chrome or a bug in the extension. Without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question someone will have to build/analyze your source code.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to make a simple MV3-only example

Comment: @wOxxOm Done. See updated question

Comment: I see `injected` in console and `injected.css` in styles panel using `https://www.google.com/` in Chrome 93-97. Try in a new browser profile without other extensions or chrome://flags.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I forgot to mention before that this problem only arises if resources are injected into a page with a local file (`file://`) opened; there is no problem on `https?://` pages.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1264366

Comment: I can confirm I have the same issue. I have a content script that loads for these URL scheme file://*/* (which works) but this script renders React component that has to access images and SVGs. when using the appropriate API runtime.getUrl(pathToMyAsset) it should load, but I get this BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT too. I have to use a work around which is svg_inline_loader in my webpack config to load the content of the svg and use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to insert the svg content in a component to display these icons properly so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, confirming this nasty behaviour in `MV3` for `file://*` scheme..
Sounds like a Chrome's CSP bug when accessing resources from local files..

As workaround we can simply proxying all `global.fetch()` requests to our service-worker (aka background-page in MV2) with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, callback)` and then return content as a plain/base64 string.

The [bug](https://crbug.com/1181450) is [fixed in Chrome 106](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/6d95bacc74a8cad81a60a81ed949954d6538b701).